# Find element by class and custom attribute value (then update it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Using jQuery I want to add some HTML to a specific `<td>` whose attribute matches the value I have.

For example I have a value '2015-02-01', I want to find/search the `<td>` which had the attribute 'data-date="2015-02-01"' and append HTML to the matched value, which in this example is `<td>1</td>`

```
<div class="fc-content-skeleton">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td data-date="2015-02-01" class="fc-day-number">1</td>
<td data-date="2015-02-02" class="fc-day-number">2</td>
<td data-date="2015-02-03" class="fc-day-number">3</td>
<td data-date="2015-02-04" class="fc-day-number">4</td>
<td data-date="2015-02-05" class="fc-day-number">5</td>
<td data-date="2015-02-06" class="fc-day-number">6</td>
<td data-date="2015-02-07" class="fc-day-number">7</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

I dont have any sample code as I am stuck really on how to approach this.

```
// This only gives me the value of the attribute
$this.parent().find('.fc-day-number').attr('data-date');
```

Comment: $this.parent().find('.fc-day-number').attr('data-date').append('test');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) whose syntax is `[attributeName[=attributeValue]]`

```
var value = "2015-02-01";
$('[data-date="' + value + '"]').append('html here');
```

Note, that you can apply the above selector in `find`, `closest` and other such jQuery methods that accept a CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks, I used: $this.parent().find('.fc-day-number').closest('[data-date="' + date_value + '"]').append('some html here');

// can probably use something other than 'closest' but it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [Attribute Equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

then use jQuery [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to add content

or use jQuery [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append content

here is the `html()` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82zL0878/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think is that you want :

```
var date = "2015-02-03";

$("td[data-date='" + date + "']").append(date);
```

Solution on this url : http://jsfiddle.net/g09jvfxy/1/